# Приложение крашится при переходе на другую активность

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]`MusicAdapter` `class` реализует `RecyclerView` и при нажатии передает объект класса `Music` через `intent` aктивности `Description`, `Description` "парсит" Объект и распихивает его поля по вьюхам, если быть корректней, то через `intent` передается фрагмент коллекции `musicList`

```
public class MusicAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<com.example.paulr.tryingtoadaptrecyclerview.MusicAdapter.MusicVH> {
    List<Music> musicList;
    private Context context;

    public MusicAdapter(List<Music> musicList) {
        this.musicList = musicList;
    }
    public MusicAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MusicVH onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nice_artist, viewGroup, false);

        return new MusicVH(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MusicVH musicVH, final int i) {
        final Music music = musicList.get(i);
        musicVH.albumImage.setImageResource(music.getAlbunImageId());
        musicVH.artist.setText(music.getArtist());
        musicVH.description.setText(music.getMusic());
        musicVH.artistCard.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                musicList.remove(i);
                notifyItemRemoved(i);
                notifyItemChanged(i);
                return false;
            }
        });
        musicVH.artistCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(musicVH.itemView.getContext(), Description.class);
               intent.putExtra("musicObject", music);
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return musicList.size();
    }


    class MusicVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements Serializable{
        private ImageView albumImage;
        private TextView artist;
        private TextView description;
        private CardView artistCard;

        public MusicVH(@NonNull View itemView, ImageView albumImage, TextView artist, TextView description) {
            super(itemView);
            this.albumImage = albumImage;
            this.artist = artist;
            this.description = description;
        }

        public MusicVH(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);



            albumImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.albumImage);
            artist = itemView.findViewById(R.id.artistName);
            description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.artistDescription);
            artistCard = itemView.findViewById(R.id.musicCard);

        }
    }
}
```

`Music` class

```
public class Music implements Serializable {

    private String artist;
    private String music;
    private int albunImageId;

    public Music(String artist, String music, int albunImageId) {
        this.artist = artist;
        this.music = music;
        this.albunImageId = albunImageId;
    }

    public Music(Object name) {

    }


    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }

    public void setArtist(String artist) {
        this.artist = artist;
    }

    public String getMusic() {
        return music;
    }

    public void setMusic(String music) {
        this.music = music;
    }

    public int getAlbunImageId() {
        return albunImageId;
    }

    public void setAlbunImageId(int albunImageId) {
        this.albunImageId = albunImageId;
    }
}
```

`Description` Activity

```
public class Description extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView albumImageV;
    private TextView artistV;
    private TextView descriptionV;
    private Music music;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_description);

        Intent intent = new Intent();
       music = (Music) intent.getSerializableExtra("musicOblect");

        albumImageV = findViewById(R.id.ImageDes);
        artistV = findViewById(R.id.artistDes);
        descriptionV = findViewById(R.id.DesDes);
```

Если раскомментить строки ниже, то приложение при попытки перехода крашнется

```
        //artistV.setText(music.getArtist());
       // albumImageV.setImageResource(music.getAlbunImageId());
       // descriptionV.setText(music.getMusic());



    }
}
```

Если понадобятся Log, то могу прикрепить, только еще бы знать какую часть, а то там все красное

Comment: Ту часть, которая описывает главную причину ошибки, и желательно стэктрейс.

Comment: У вас опечатка при получении значения из intent. Вот почему нужно пользоваться psfs переменными ;)

Comment: @Jarvis_J ma god... ty

Comment: @Jarvis_J исправил, но не помогло

Comment: Тогда стэктрейс показывайте уже

Comment: 95% у вас NullPointerException, т.к. `albumImageV, artistV, descriptionV` - null. Все или кто-то из них. Внимательно проверьте разметку, и убедитесь, что вы там ничего не напутали в ID вьюх.